# Read from named pipe and pipe to secondary process

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdin

I have this:

```
delete_lock(){
  first_arg=$1
}

node x.js | delete_lock $0 < ${my_named_pipe} &
```

I am looking to read from my_named_pipe into the stdin of the node.js process, and upon certain input, then write to stdout in the node.js process which would then be captured by delete_lock.

My main question is, how can I reference stdin in delete_lock in bash?
I don't think it's $0, how can I do it?

Is this the only way to do it?

```
node x.js | { while read line; delete_lock $line; } < ${my_named_pipe} &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you need the Node application to read from the pipe, then let's do that:

```
node x.js <"$my_named_pipe"
```

Then you say you want the function to read the output from that, then let's do that too:

```
node x.js <"$my_named_pipe" | delete_lock
```

Note that `|` is a command terminator, which means that in

```
command1 | command2 <thing
```

it's `command2` that reads from `thing`.

---

Responding to comments:

The `delete_lock` function can read its standard input, which comes from the Node application.  If it, for example, has to do some action depending on a pattern in the output from the Node application, it may want to use `grep`:

```
delete_lock () {
    if grep -q 'PATTERN'; then
        # some command here
    fi
}
```

If you need the Node application to keep going after the action has been performed by the function, then you need to continue consuming its output:

```
delete_lock () {
    if grep -q 'PATTERN'; then
        # some command here
    fi
    cat >/dev/null
}
```

Otherwise, the Node application will receive a SIGPIPE signal and terminate.

Comment: thanks, do you have thoughts on alternative to using `read` to get a var representing stdin?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I don't really see a use for that. `delete_lock` can parse the output of the Node application in any way it wants. If it wants to act on certain input, then use `grep -q` (for example) on the input stream. Basically, I can't say much about this because you have not described what `delete_lock` needs to be doing.

Comment: yeah I don't follow - maybe can you add an example of delete_lock reading from the node command? I am not so good at bash that I know how, I can only guess that the read command would then go inside the delete_lock function.

Comment: @AlexanderMills See updated answer.

Comment: yeah see I don't understand how to read the input - how I can reference the stdin - say "dog" is sent to stdin, how do I reference it? (in the delete_lock function).

Comment: Maybe this question makes it more clear: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439021/reference-the-stdin-sent-from-piped-sender-process

Comment: @AlexanderMills Just `grep -q 'dog'`. `grep` will read from standard input by default if you don't give it a filename, and standard input (within the function) comes directly from the Node application.

Comment: dog could be anything, I don't know what dog is in advance. I think it needs to be `while read line; ...` then I inspect the line.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll look at your new question.