# Reference the stdin sent from piped sender process

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

Say I have this:

```
delete_lock () {
    if grep -q 'PATTERN'; then
        # some command here
    fi
    cat >/dev/null
}

node foo.js | delete_lock
```

say the node.js process writes "foodog" to delete_lock, or it sends "sandbag". (It could be any unique name...)

How can I read that in the delete_lock function? delete_lock is going to receive some unique name and then delete the lock with that name from the filesystem...how can I do that?

The only thing that I can guess, is something like this:

```
  delete_lock () {
        if grep -q 'lockname:xxx'; then
            release_lock $xxx
        fi
        cat >/dev/null
  }
```

but how do I reference the variable $xxx lol?

Comment: Does the Node application produce a _single_ line with a value that you want to capture, or is it a long stream that you don't want to interrupt but you'd like to find a pattern in and use it?

Comment: `if xxx=$(grep -o 'pattern'); then ...; fi`

Comment: @Kusalananda probably ongoing stream, not just one line, but it would be nice to know how to do it in both scenarios

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `xxx` is a stand-in for a pattern of some sort.

```bash
delete_lock () {
    LOCK="$(grep -m1 -o "lockname:xxx")"
    if [ -n "${LOCK#lockname:}" ]; then
        release_lock "${LOCK#lockname:}"
    fi
}

node foo.js | delete_lock
```

This will stop processing data once it observes the first match for `lockname:xxx`.  It then uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove the `lockname:` prefix and, assuming there was a match (e.g. `xxx`, runs `release_lock` on it (e.g. `release_lock "xxx"`).

If you don't want the `node` call to be cut short, or you want more than one match, remove the `-m1` option to `grep`, though note the quotes may not work with your `release_lock` code (and be careful about removing those quotes, you don't want to allow rogue characters!).